# Show the colour of the badge awarded in the android app feed

Tags: feature-request, badges, android-app, notifications, android-app-feed

When you get a badge they appear in the android app feed. Currently there's a little badge icon next to the title of the badge. At the moment it's always grey; I think it would be nice to add the colour of the badge.